# Distance between point in space and a line

Tags: geometry

Suppose given is a triangle $XYZ$. Line $YP$ is perpendiculas to the plane of the triangle. How can we find the distance from $P$ to the line $XZ$?

Idea: We are given that $YP $ is perpendicular to $YX$ and $YZ$. Can I pick any arbitrary point on the line $XZ$? say point $Q$. Then $PYQ$ would be a right triangle so we can use pythagorean theorem. IS this a correct reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The point $Q$ cannot be arbitrary, but it must be the point on $XZ$ that minimize the length $PQ$. This means that it is such that $Q$ is the height of the triangle $XYZ$. Can you find this point? (Or the length $YQ$?)

Comment: I think I got it. So, from point $Y$ I drop the the altitude to point $Q$ in line $XZ$ so that distance from $P$ to $XZ$ would be $\sqrt{ |QY|^2 + |PY|^2} $. am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct!